# Create custom function to extend default jQuery $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to create a function that extends `jQuery` `$.ajax` callbacks.
In specific, I need to **add** a default code to every `beforeSend()`, `complete()` callback.
For instance, I have tried this:

```
var custom = {};
var tempAjax = function(options,callback){ 
    var defaults = { };
    $.extend(options,defaults);
    return $.ajax(options);
}
custom.ajax = function() {
    if ( !arguments[0].beforeSend ) {
        arguments[0].beforeSend = function() {
            // my default code
        }
    }
    return tempAjax.apply($, arguments).then(function(value) {
        // my default code
    }).fail( function() {
        // my default code
    });
}
```

it is important that every other `$.ajax` call will still run the own specific code in addition of the default code I have defined.
So the following code:

```
custom.ajax({
    url:        url,
    data:       data,
    dataType:   type,
    beforeSend: function(result){   
        // other code
    },
    success: function(result){  
        // other code
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        // other code
    },
    complete: function () { 
        // other code
    }
});
```

will run `// other code` **and** `// my default code` for each callback type.

I'm not sure my solution is working as expected.
Could you help me with that?

**edit**: it is also important that the default code will be used by `custom.ajax` and not by standard `$.ajax` calls that will continue to run normally.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If the order of execution doesn't matter, then I believe you could use jQuery's global event handlers for your [beforeSend](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/), [success](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/), [error](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) and [complete](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) cases.

My understanding is that those will be called for all $.ajax calls afterwards...

Hope this helps!